# Can every parabola be written in the form of a quadratic $y=ax^2+bx+c$ or $x=dy^2+ey+f$?

Tags: calculus, conic-sections, quadratics

I understand that the graph of any equation of the form $y=ax^2+bx+c$ is a parabola (please correct me if I am mistaken).

My question is about the converse: Can every parabola be written in the form of an equation $y=ax^2+bx+c$ or $x=dy^2+ey+f$?

Comment: Well, it can, as long as it's a function, I think. You can find this using that the definition of a parabola is a set of  points that are a equal distance from a point and a line, then using the pythagorean theorem.

Comment: How about $x=y^2$?

Comment: Any turned parabola, which is not a function, cannot be written such a way. (Spin a parabola).

Comment: @MXYMXY: Thanks for pointing that out. I've rewritten my question.

Comment: You don't have to turn it by 90 degrees.

Comment: $(x-y)=(x+y)^2$ is also a parabola and is not in the form you write. I think the correct statement is every parabola can be written in the form $ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f=0$ where $b^2-4ac=0$. It takes a while to prove though.

Comment: But not everything that can be described by that equation is a parabola.

Comment: @frank000 The proof may be be done in two steps: we can show it's true for canonical form of the equation AND it's invariant under any translations, rotations and scaling of a curve on an $XY$ plane..

Answer (score 3):

A parabola is just the locus of points (a collection) that is equidistant from a point and a straight line. Let $(x,y)$ be the set of points, then for let's say you have a fixed point $(p,q)$ and a line $ax+by+c=0$,

The distance between $(x,y)$ and the straight line is given by:

$$\frac{|ax+by+c|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$

We want to set that to be equal to the distance between $(p,q)$ and $(x,y)$

$$ \frac{|ax+by+c|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}=\sqrt{(x-p)^2+(y-q)^2}$$

$$\frac{a^2x^2+b^2y^2+2abxy+2acx+2bcy}{a^2+b^2}=x^2-2px+p^2+y^2-2qx+q^2$$

---

$$b^2x^2+a^2y^2-(2p(a^2+b^2)+2ac)x-(2q(a^2+b^2)+2bc)y-2abxy+(p^2+q^2)(a^2+b^2)=0$$

So the formula doesn't look pleasant, but we know from that, any parabola will be in the form of $ax^2+by^2+cx+dy+exy+f=0$

Answer (score 2):

The parabolas whose axes of symmetry is parallel to x- or y- axis belong to the category you mention. They are characterized by an absence of $xy$ term which when present, makes its axis of symmetry *inclined* to the coordinate axes.

From the general equation of conics using an invariance condition $I_2=0$ for unity eccentricity  of parabola we have

$$ a x^2 + 2  h x y + b y^2 + 2 g x+ 2 f y + 1 = 0,\, h^2 - a b =0 ;$$

when solved for $y$ as a quadratic and constants are re-lumped, it assumes a form for the *inclined parabola*:

$$  \boxed {y = (A x + B) \pm \sqrt{ C x + D } } $$

The two branches are separated by vertical/horizontal tangents when $ C x + D =0 $

[image: IncclinedParabola]

Answer (score 1):

To sum up the comments: No.

But you're not completely wrong. Parabolas are "just" geometric shapes, they don't require a coordinate system, but if you add a coordinate system with axes parallel to the directrix and the axis if symmetry (see [Wikipedia in parabolas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola)) if can be described by one of the two forms you have listed.

Answer (score 0):

If it is any parabola in the plane you would need $$ax^2+by^2+cxy+dy+ex+f = 0$$, this becomes evident if you try and for example rotate your parabola:
$$x_0 = \cos(\alpha)x + \sin(\alpha)y\\y_0 = -\sin(\alpha)x + \cos(\alpha)y$$
You will be getting the "mixed terms" containing $xy$ when converting $x^2$ and $y^2$ into $x_0$ and $y_0$. Some special $\alpha$ maybe pose no problem but for most of them you will be getting the cross-terms.